# Joining tables for dynamic results?

Tags: sql, database, join

I'm trying to join these two tables. Let's call one Employees, and the other Employee Information:

```
Employees
Name         Title         ID
-------      -------     ------
John         Consultant    1
John         Engineer      2
Jane         Accountant    3

Employee Information
Name         EmailAddress    Project
------       -------------   ----------
John         John@work.com    Travelling
John         John1@work.com   Database Maintenance
```

I'm trying to join the tables to look like this:

```
Desired Results
Name      Title       EmailAddress     Project
------    -----       -------------    ----------
John     Consultant   John@work.com    Travelling
John     Engineer     John1@work.com   Database Maintenance
```

But I keep getting something like this:

```
Actual Results
Name      Title       EmailAddress     Project
------    -----       -------------    ----------
John     Consultant   John@work.com    Travelling
John     Engineer     John@work.com    Database Maintenance
John     Consultant   John1@work.com   Travelling
John     Engineer     John1@work.com   Database Maintenance
```

I'm running a query similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees E INNER JOIN
EmployeeInformation EI ON E.Name = EI.Name
```

Looking at it, I can understand why the number of rows doubles, but I can't seem to figure out a way to get the desired output, any suggestions? Or is it not possible since my filters are too vague?

Answer (score 0):

You're joining on a non-unique field, which means that it will return one row for each E.Name = "John"/EI.Name = "John" combination.

To fix this, you need to find or create a field that has a 1:1 relationship between your two tables. (assuming that each employee only has one row in your EI table.)

For example, can you leverage E.ID to match on your EI table?

If the data has been well structured, there should be a foreign key field on your EI table that corrosponds to the primary key (should be E.ID) in your Employee table.

Answer (score 0):

`Employeeinformation` table should have the primary key of `employees` table.
Please change your table structure ,try Add one more column to `Employee information`table and update ID from `employees` table.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is telling me:

```
John has three titles.
John has two email addresses.
There is no relations that tells us which email goes with which title.
```

That fact is fundamentally why you see the results you are seeing. Your data says that both emails go with all titles. Your schema needs to change if you want to assign specific email addresses to specific person/title combinations.